# Raphaël, draw and resize vertical lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

I am creating a custom jQuery UI Widget for a corporate project where I need to draw vertical lines on 2-axis scrollable scale. This is what I am currently using, from what I found to be the "best practice" :

```
var tick = this.eventsPaper.path("M" + x + ",0L" + x + "," + this._height).attr({
    stroke: this.options.eventsForeground
})s
```

On that `eventsPaper` are events that can be inserted and removed and, by doing so, may change the vertical (ie. `this._height`) of the events paper required to display all events.

Right now, I am clearing all the lines and redrawing all of them everytime the height changes, but I'd like to optimize this part by simply resizing the vertical lines.

1. Is this a good idea?
2. What is the best (fastest) way of achieving this?

   1. If not, I suppose redrawing all these lines *is* the most optimal way, am I right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most UAs will be faster if you don't recreate the lines.

Let's say that your element is something like this...

```
<path id="path1" d="M5,0L5,10"/>
```

so

```
var path = document.getElementById("path1");
var start = path.pathSegList.getItem(0);
var end = path.pathSegList.getItem(1);

// and now you can do things like this...

start.y = 20;
end.y += 50;
```